# The private key for is not installed on this mac

Tags: ios, xcode, private-key, iphone-developer-program

I wanted to use xcode for particular project in a machine other than usually i am working. I tried to archive the project and got an error "The private key for is not installed on this mac - distributing”
Then i exported the developer profile and problem solved. But it doest work in the first machine. how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to export your Certificate (Developer and/or Distribution) from your keychain as .p12 file and import it to the other machines.